# Binary tree search not returning matching value when some nodes are null

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

TL;DR - How do I alter this algorithm to return the matching val given a BST with null nodes?

TreeNode:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
 *     this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {TreeNode} root
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {TreeNode}
 */
```

Given a binary tree, find the matching val.  My algorithm is below

```
var searchBST = function(root, val) {
    const matchingNode = visitNode(root, val);
    // if no match, return null
    return matchingNode ? matchingNode : null;
};

const visitNode = (node, val) => {
    if (node.left !== null) {
        return visitNode(node.left, val)
    }
    if (node.right !== null) {
        return visitNode(node.right, val)
    }
    if (node.val === val) {
        console.log('MATCH!')
        return node;
    }
}
```

This works for standard trees with no `null` values, such as [4,2,7,1,3] and empty trees [].

I'm having an issue with trees that have null nodes, such as [18, 2, 22, null, null, null, 63, null, 84, null, null].

The function seems to stop prematurely.  If I remove the returns in the first two if blocks, I'm able to stop recursing at the matching val, but unable to get the value to be returned.

How do I alter this algorithm to return the matching val given a BST with null nodes?

Comment: Looks like you need some OR logic rather than just `return left subtree`. What if it's in the right subtree? Also, if this is a BST, you probably want to use a comparator function to take advantage of the structure to improve your lookup time from O(n) to O(n log(n)) (but start by fixing your bug...)

Comment: @ggorlen wow, I'm an idiot.  pretty sure that changing the `return visitNode(...)` part to `foundNode = visitNode(...)`... and returning the found node would work.  Ugh

Comment: Sure, or just `return visitNode(node.left, val) || visitNode(node.right, val)` as long as you check the base case `if (!node) return null` up front. Again, use the comparator though--the code here is just for searching binary trees rather than BSTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider the following refactored version of `visitNode()` below.  The base case occurs when the incoming node be `null`, in which case the function just returns `null`.  Otherwise, it checks if the current node matches the sought after value.  If not, then it traverses either the left or right recursively.

```js
const visitNode = (node, val) => {
    if (node == null) return null;

    if (node.val === val) {
        console.log('MATCH!')
        return node;
    }

    if (val < node.val) {
        return visitNode(node.left, val);
    }
    else {
        return visitNode(node.right, val)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I've been an software engineer for 6 years and totally forgot that in a BST, the right node value is always larger than the parent node value.  And reversed for the left side.  THAT WOULDA HELPED! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for binary search tree, try this

```
if (node == null || node.val === val) 
   return node;
 
// val is greater than node's val
if (node->val < val) 
   return visitNode(node.right, val); 

// val is smaller than node's val
return visitNode(node.left, val);
```

Or you have to traverse the tree by [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: Do BST always follow the rules that "currentNode.val < val (go right)"?